# Using tabularx, multirow, and parbox for line-wrapping

Tags: tables, boxes, tabularx, multirow

I am using a `multirow` inside a `tabularx`, but because the `multirow` doesn't wrap, I am putting the `multirow`'s text inside a `parbox` environment:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}} \toprule
blah & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{\columnwidth}{blah}} \\
blah & \\
\end{tabularx}
```

What should I put as the `parbox`'s width so that it responds to the column width that tabularx chooses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\linewidth`, since that will be the width of the column as adjusted by `tabularx`'s `X`-column. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{tabularx,multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}} \toprule
blah & \multirow{2}{*}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{blah}}} \\
blah & \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Contrary to belief, `\columnwidth` does not span the width of a table column.

Answer (score 9):

`\multirow`  would linewrap if you passed a length rather than `*`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{tabularx,multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\def\blah{blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}} \toprule
\blah & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\blah \blah} \\
\blah & \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @David for your suggestion on explicit passing of the length