# Table formatting problem with multiple multi-rows

Tags: tabularx, multirow

I am trying to complete the formatting of this table. I cannot get the text in the final column to wrap and remain in the cell.

The "stuff stuff stuff" text just keeps going off the edge of the page.

Also, I cannot get the heading separators to work.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
Section & Sub-Section & Description & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Key} \\ \hline
& Stage & The  & Stuff & \\ \cline{2-4} 
& Stuff  & The & Stuff & \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-3}{*}{Stuff} & Stuff & The  & Cole & \multirow{-3}{*}{Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff } \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` scaling tables is (almost) always wrong, but scaling a table to `\textwidth` when its size is already forced to `\textwidth` in the `tabularx` argument is.. odd (also if you do use `\scalebox` you need a `%` and no blank line after the `{` )

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! You will have to give the `multirow` a width. `\multirow{-3}{2.3cm}{` for example... (but the last cell is to small to fit all this "stuff"

Comment: Also please next time make your example a complete document so that people can run it and see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed from `\small` to `\scriptsize` in order to fit everything in your cells. You may reformat your table with differing width in each row. Or maybe the original text fits for your chosen fontsize.

The main [trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87389) was to give the `multirow` a certain width. As the `X`-column is stretchable, the `multirow` does not know the actual width. If you do not want to search this discrete value, you may use `\hsize`. `\hsize` works because it happens internally inside the `X`-column set up for the table and `X` (and `p`) sets `\hsize` so line breaking works correctly within the cell. So you can use `\hsize` here to tell `multirow` to use the size that `tabularx` decided to use.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype} % handy in narrow cells with much text

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \scriptsize       
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
        Section & Sub-Section & Description & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Key} \\ \hline
        & Stage & The  & Stuff & \\ \cline{2-4} 
        & Stuff  & The & Stuff & \\ \cline{2-4}
        \multirow{-3}{*}{Stuff} & Stuff & The  & Cole & \multirow{-3}{\hsize}{Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff } \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]